# Azure DevOps Git: Fork into another Repo using Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

In my Azure DevOps Project, I have a Git repository that I would like to copy to another Azure DevOps Project.

In other words, I should be able to copy the original repo into other Azure DevOps projects as needed.

I'm trying to achieve this using the Azure DevOps REST APIs, but I haven't found enough documentation. The only thing I see is the ability to create new repos using the Azure DevOps REST APIs, but nothing about copying the contents of the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I should be able to copy the original repo into other Azure DevOps
> projects as needed.

**Fork:**

We can call the [Repositories - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to fork the repo from one project to another within the same Azure DevOps organization. The following PowerShell script for your reference:

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}", 
   [string]$sourceproject = "Artifacts",
   [string]$targetproject = "Basic",
   [string]$sourcereponame = "Artifacts",
   [string]$forkreponame = "Artifacts.fork",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get source project ID
$sourceprojecturl = "$orgurl/_apis/projects/$($sourceproject)?api-version=6.0"
$sourceprojectid = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $sourceprojecturl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).id

#Get source repo ID
$sourcerepourl = "$orgurl/$sourceproject/_apis/git/repositories/$($sourcereponame)?api-version=6.0"
$sourcerepoid = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $sourcerepourl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).id

#Get target project ID
$targetprojecturl = "$orgurl/_apis/projects/$($targetproject)?api-version=6.0"
$targetprojectid = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $targetprojecturl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).id

#Create Jason body

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
    {
        "name": "$forkreponame",
        "parentRepository": {
            "id": "$sourcerepoid",
            "project": {
                "id": "$sourceprojectid"
            }
        },
        "project": {
            "id": "$targetprojectid",
            "name": "$targetproject"
        }
    }
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$forkuri = "$orgurl/$targetproject/_apis/git/Repositories?api-version=6.0"
$forkresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $forkuri -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$forkresult
```

As we can see the fork repo is created:
[image]

**Import Git repo from one project to another:**

Another way is importing the original Git repo from one project to another. Get the clone URL from the original Git repo, create a PAT, then import. See [Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops) for details.

If you want to do that by calling REST API, the following PowerShell for your reference (projects within the same Azure DevOps organization):

```
Param(
   [string]$organization = "organization name here",
   [string]$sourceproject = "source project name",
   [string]$targetproject = "target project name",
   [string]$sourceRepoName = "source git repo name",
   [string]$targetRepoName = "target repo name",
   [string]$username = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$targetUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$targetproject/_apis"

# create endpoint
$endpoint = irm "$targetUrl/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.0-preview" -Method:Post -ContentType "application/json" `
   -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} `
   -Body ( '{{"name":"temporary-script-git-import3","type":"git","url":"https://{4}@dev.azure.com/{4}/{0}/_git/{1}","authorization":{{"parameters":{{"username":"{2}","password":"{3}"}},"scheme":"UsernamePassword"}}}}' -f $sourceproject, $sourceRepoName, $username, $token, $organization )

# import repository
$importRepo = irm "$targetUrl/git/repositories/$targetRepoName/importRequests?api-version=5.0-preview" -Method:Post -ContentType "application/json" `
   -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} `
   -Body ( '{{"parameters":{{"deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone":true,"gitSource":{{"url":"https://{3}@dev.azure.com/{3}/{0}/_git/{1}","overwrite":false}},"tfvcSource":null,"serviceEndpointId":"{2}"}}}}' -f $sourceproject, $sourceRepoName, $endpoint.id, $organization )
```

Comment: I like the first approach and I will give you a try. How do I pass the Pat for both source and destination as both of these will be in a different organization?

Comment: @MugilKarthikeyan Currently we cannot fork repo across organizations in Azure DevOps. In this case, we can use the second way to import the repo from one org to another.